# Accessing http object in a Node.js module

Tags: node.js, socket.io

OK, can someone tell me what's going on? I have this in my main file:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(function (req,resp){
     console.log("Started");                                              
});

http.listen(1337);
```

I start the server and console.log doesn't log anything. I load a webpage, and every time I load it, I get the console.log("Started") message. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log()` is run inside the HTTP request listener function, which only runs when the HTTP server receives a request. When you create the server, the listener function isn't invoked, so `console.log()` doesn't run.

If you want the message to run on HTTP server listen, use it in the `listen()` function's callback.

```
server.listen(80, function() {
  // this runs when the server has been started
});
```

Comment: A-doi! I should have figured that one out. I was messing around with express the other day. much appreciated, sir. I'll vote in a couple of minutes when it lets me.